# Tab-completion of filenames as arguments for MATLAB scripts

Tags: matlab, filenames, tab-completion

We all know MATLAB provides tab-completion for filenames used as arguments in MATLAB function like `importdata`,`imread`. How do we do that for the functions we create?

**EDIT:**

[image]

Displays the files and folders in the current directory.

Comment: Are you talking about how you can type the first part of the function name in the Editor or Command Window, then hit tab to get a list of function names that complete it? All of the functions that I've written that are on the current MATLAB path show up when I do this.

Comment: I'll have to check tomorrow (when I have access to MATLAB), but I *think* MATLAB will do a tab-completion with directories/files as the suggestions whenever you start typing in a string value.

Comment: @gnovice: Nope. With imread() then yes, typing a "'" and pressing tab shows a list of files. Trying that with a function I wrote myself does not have that behaviour.

Comment: You can look at the source code of the functions to see how it could be done. At least you can do it for the two functions you have proposed.

Comment: @prm: Sadly, the source code for imread() shows nothing that indicates that it has that functionality.

Comment: @prm: Yeah, I already checked the code, nothing there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Caution: unsupported hack here.

Take a look at the file toolbox\local\TC.xml in your Matlab installation. This appears to contain the argument type mappings for tab completion. (I found this by just grepping the Matlab installation for "imread" in R2009b.)

Adding this line inside the `<TC>` element will get you tab-completion of file names for each of its arguments.

```
<binding name="importdata"        ctype="FILE"/>
```

This requires modifying the Matlab installation in place. For some of the other files in toolbox/local, like classpath.txt, you can override them by placing modified copies in the directory you start Matlab from, but this didn't work for TC.xml for me.

Comment: Is this solution, 6 years later and in version R2015b still valid? As in: is there now a non-hacking way to do this and/or is this way still working?

Comment: There still is no official "non-hacking way" to do this, but see here (http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-desktop-tab-completions) for a slightly less hackish way (still requiring write access to TC.xml, unfortunately).

Answer (score 5):

There is no supported way to add your functions to the argument Tab completion, but one trick I use is to put a "!" in front of the command so it is treated like a system command. Tab will then complete file paths. Once my MATLAB command is done, I home to the beginning of the line, delete the "!" and press enter.

Answer (score 5):

**For Matlab 2016a and above :**

The file Tc.xml is not present in Matlab 2016a onwards. It uses a **.json** (Java Script Object Notation) file to achieve the same. A simple example of this can be  as follows.

Suppose you have a Matlab function file called **`myFunction.m`**. Furthermore, suppose that this function needs files with extension **`.ext`** as input and you want the tab-completion to show all possible input options for this function. Then, write the following content in a file and name it **`functionSignatures.json`**.

```
{
"myFunction":
{
  "inputs":
  [
    {"name":"filename", "kind":"required", "type":"filepath=*.ext" }
  ]
}
}
```

Place this file in the same directory as **`myFunction.m`** file. Now, restart Matlab.

**What this file does :** While typing in the function input, upon pressing tab, you will see a list of files with the extension **`.ext`** popping up. If you want all the files to be shown in tab completion popup irrespective of their extension, then replace `"type":"filepath=*.ext"` with `"type":"filepath"` in the file **`functionSignatures.json`**.

**Source** : https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/306157-how-to-configure-tab-completion-for-my-function-in-matlab-2016#answer_237857

Comment: Just to emphasize, restarting Matlab is important when a new .json files is created - without it Matlab will not see it.