# Tab completion of custom class methods in Matlab

Tags: matlab, class, tab-completion

I made a custom class where files are loaded by the constructor and by methods (the path is given as input), e.g.:

**Classdeclaration:**

```
classdef Foo > handle
  methods
    function o = Foo(file), end
    function bar(o,file), end
  end
end
```

**TC.xml file**:

```
  <binding name="Foo" ctype="FILE"/>
  <binding name="bar" ctype="MCOSCLASS FILE"/>
```

**Matlab command prompt:**

`s = Foo('` + `Tab` does list available files.

`s.bar('` + `Tab` works

But the problem is that Tab completion is not limited to the class Foo. The trick to change the `TC.xsd` did not help as well unfortunatly. Yair Altman help me luckely so far to get to this point. Thx again for that.

The whole procedure can be found [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-desktop-tab-completions/):

Comment: you could ask Yair Altman directly on his blog... he will probably know how to do this :)

Comment: Since `object.add(arg)` is identical to `add(object, arg)` in Matlab, you might want to try putting `add` with the corresponding two arguments into the xml.

Comment: @sebastian. Nice idea, unforturnatly it didn't work. -If I tried it correctly, which is quite doubtfull. But yeah one should anyway use your Sintax

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, here is a related topic, which contains an answer to a similar question: [Tab-completion of filenames as arguments for MATLAB scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842804/tab-completion-of-filenames-as-arguments-for-matlab-scripts)

Then, here is an article on a good Matlab portal on the same topic: [Setting desktop tab completions | Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-desktop-tab-completions/)

UPD: Unfortunately, although there were some TAB-completion [improvements introduced in the version R2010a](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/03/22/tab-completion-in-the-matlab-r2010a-editor/),

> Because tab completion uses static analysis, it doesn’t try to guess
>   at the data type for a variable, so things after a “.” such as
>   properties and fields won’t be completed unless that variable is also
>   defined in the workspace.

And it is dubious if there is some more recent info on topic (at least, I did not find any).

Therefore, it is *most probably* not possible in current version to auto-complete dot properties and methods in MatLab without statically adding all of them to the *.XML file.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @magu_, oops, sorry, I should sleep more! I'll update my answer as fast as I find something out!