# How to make MATLAB's autocomplete look for files for a custom function?

Tags: matlab, autocomplete

MATLAB autocompletes for file lookups in functions like `imread`. How can it autocomplete for a file name parameter in a function I've written?

Comment: This can be done through editing MATLAB's tab completion file. See here: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-desktop-tab-completions/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842804/tab-completion-of-filenames-as-arguments-for-matlab-scripts